# Text won't show up using innerText or innerHTML

Tags: javascript

as the title said and i'm learning javascript and still a beginner.

This the Html file here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>jQuery</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="menu"></h1>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function clr(o){
    var a1 = [];
    var i = 0;
    for (var k in o){
        a1[i] = 0;
        i++;
    }
    return a1;
   }
   console.log(clr({a:"a", b:"b", c:"c"}));
   document.getElementsByClassName("menu").innerText = clr({a:"a", b:"b", c:"c"});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: just test it yourself and tell me what's the problem, the page still empty!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running Jquery you can use Jquery method. like `text()` or `html()`

But your problem, is that `document.getElementsByClassName("menu")` return an HTML Collection so you have to do : `document.getElementsByClassName("menu")[0].innerHTML`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>jQuery</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="menu"></h1>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function clr(o){
    var a1 = [];
    var i = 0;
    for (var k in o){
        a1[i] = 0;
        i++;
    }
    return a1;
   }
   console.log(clr({a:"a", b:"b", c:"c"}));
   $(".menu").text(clr({a:"a", b:"b", c:"c"}));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName("menu")` will return an Array-like NodeList of elements that contain the class `menu`.

Since its an Array-like object, you need to access individual elements using `[]`.

In your case, it will be a an array of 1 element, the `h1` element, so to access it you need to grab it at position `0`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("menu")[0].innerHTML = clr({a:"a", b:"b", c:"c"});
----------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited a couple a things. You were close.
I gave the h1 an id. And used document.getElementById.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>jQuery</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="menu"></h1>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function clr(o){
    var a1 = [];
    var i = 0;
    for (var k in o){
        a1[i] = 0;
        i++;
    }
    return a1;
   }
   console.log(clr({a:"a", b:"b", c:"c"}));
   document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML = clr({a:"a", b:"b", c:"c"});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```